# How does this function not use an extra argument

Tags: javascript

This JavaScript is from Resig's code in his [JavaScript Ninja](http://manning.com/resig/) book:

```
function yell(n){ 
  return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
} 
assert( yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "Calling the function by itself comes naturally." );
```

So it's some simple recursion.  I understand recursion.  This is probably a dumb question.  However, I don't understand why this works in so few lines of code.  Where does the `"aaaa"` get appended to `"hiy"`?  If I was doing this in say Prolog, I think I would have added an extra parameter to `yell` to keep track of the string being built.

Comment: Look at what the function does after calling itself.

Comment: This is simple enough you could probably run through it on paper.  It might help to understand it.

Comment: @barakmanos No, it's four "a"s (4, 3, 2, 1) and one "hiy" (0)

Comment: These things are easier to grasp if you unfurl the ternary: https://gist.github.com/Squeegy/8718165

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function builds up the string by appending `"a"` to the return value of the *next* invocation at each step. It might help to visualize the call stack:

```
yell(4) = yell(3) + "a"
yell(3) = yell(2) + "a"
yell(2) = yell(1) + "a"
yell(1) = yell(0) + "a"
yell(0) = "hiy"
```

We now have all the information necessary to see how this works. We just need to "unroll" the stack and plug it back in:

```
yell(1) = "hiy" + "a"
yell(2) = "hiy" + "a" + "a"
yell(3) = "hiy" + "a" + "a" + "a"
yell(4) = "hiy" + "a" + "a" + "a" + "a"
```

So the final result is:

```
"hiyaaaa"
```

The reason you don't need an additional param is that no stage of the recursion needs access to the value from a *previous* step. Instead, each value is returning the combination of its value and the *next* value in the progression.

Answer (score 2):

Let's decompose a call to `yell(3)`:

```
yell(3) - n > 0 ? yell(2) + "a" : "hiy";
yell(2) - n > 0 ? yell(1) + "a" : "hiy";
yell(1) - n > 0 ? yell(0) + "a" : "hiy";
yell(0) - n > 0 ? yell(-1) + "a" : "hiy";
```

We can evaluate the conditional expressions:

```
yell(3) - yell(2) + "a";
yell(2) - yell(1) + "a";
yell(1) - yell(0) + "a";
yell(0) - "hiy";
```

Then continue to substitute/simplify:

```
yell(3) - (yell(1) + "a") + "a";          // since yell(2) = yell(1) + "a"

yell(3) - ((yell(0) + "a") + "a") + "a";  // since yell(1) = yell(0) + "a"

yell(3) - (("hiy" + "a") + "a") + "a";    // since yell(0) = "hiy"
```

And there you have it.

An important reason that this works is that the `?:` operator uses short-circuit evaluation and only evaluates the part that is relevant given the outcome of the condition. If it didn't have that, this function would result in infinite recursion.

Comment: A (pretty pedantic) note: I don't think I would refer to this as short-circuit evaluation. This is just the definition of the conditional operator. In other words, this only ever evaluates one or other of the final operands (i.e. never both).

Comment: It may not be perfectly correct use of the terminology, but I think it fits. The vast majority of operators in JavaScript only execute once all of their operands have already been evaluated. `?:`, `&&`, and `||` are among the select few that deviate from this.

Comment: I'm definitely being fussy. The `&&` and `||` are called short-circuit operators because they *can* evaluate both of their operands or they can stop early (i.e. short-circuit). The `?:` doesn't have this property. But, anyway, I don't feel too strongly about it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the ternary operator `?:` as

```
function yell(n) {
    if (n > 0)
        return yell(n - 1) + "a";
    else
        return "hiy";
}
```

The function calls itself recursively with argument `n - 1` until the argument `n` becomes `0`, where it returns `hiy`. Then recursion is wound up and one `a` is appended per recursion level.